# EC ElGamal in Bouncy castle for Java

Tags: java, cryptography, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

(this is purely for academic purposes)

I have got RSA and ElGamal implemented using bouncy castle, But I am not sure how to impliment EC ElGamal. section 4.4 in the bouncy castle spec says: "The org.bouncycastle.crypto.ec package contains implementations for a variety of EC cryptographic transforms such as EC ElGamal" However it doesn't go about explaining how to use it.

I have got as far as using the named curves in the key pair generation

```
ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("prime192v1")
```

But I don't know the algorithm reference e.g. "AES", "RSA" to put the initialisation calls

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algorithm, provider);
```

Or if anything else needs to be changed when using ECC? I take it the message size limit in ECC is based on the curve size? the above example being 192-bits.

Comment: See this related [answer on crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9990/1172) that shows how a message can be converted to a point.

Comment: And [this answer by Rasmus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6664005/589259) should give you the final piece of the puzzle.

Comment: That second link was useful, So, bouncy castle doesn't have encoding such as the koblitz method built in?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't seen it, but it looks like the ec crypto received quite an overhaul. Better ask at the crypto-dev mailinglist of bouncy castle instead of here.

Comment: Looked through the source code. I've seen mention of Koblitz curves and support for point compression, but no mention of a Koblitz method as such. I tried to do this using a point compression trick but that failed.

Comment: I have joined the dev mailing list and asked there. I shall see what that comes up with. I guess since using EC El Gamal directly is not usually done, then the facilities for it may not be as strongly developed.

Comment: As there is nothing directly targeting the EC ElGamal encryption (no references at all, not even in the sparse testing library) I guess that may be more true than you might expect...

Answer (score 2):

With `ECElGamalEncryptor` you can only encrypt a point on the curve. This is actually the same with *textbook* RSA (i.e. modular exponentiation) where you can only encrypt a big integer (less than the modulus).

You should be using a scheme such as ECIES to encrypt with Elliptic Curve cryptography. ECIES basically uses static Diffie-Hellman to encrypt messages.

Comment: I know what ECIES is. Like I said this is purely academic, I am running tests on different implementations.  How do I use `ECElGamalEncryptor`? Does bouncy castle have encoding functionality to turn a message into a point? or is that built into the engine?

Comment: OK, got to admit that I've got stuck with this too for now.