# Elliptic curve point - verify point is on the curve

Tags: openssl, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to verify that an EC point is on the curve. I've looked at a dozen similar issues around, but still can't get it right. I'm using OpenSSL (in C).

Long story short, my software has generated an EC POINT which 3rd party client has deemed as 'invalid'. Okay...

> Here's the point:
> 5F921B550C05812CF35BAE27B3A2085709DC97824C1C120F8FA357297D5CB8758F14DF103FD4B7DF68DACC110F592CEE0637810087A39D371A13D75DFDEB890F

1. OpenSSL has two functions:
   EC_POINT_is_at_infinity() and EC_POINT_is_on_curve(). Both pass (i.e. it's a valid point according to OpenSSL). Is the OpenSSL verification insufficient?
2. Other threads have suggested using the 'y2 = x3 + ax + b' equation. So I try:
   Curve: prime256v1 (also referred to as secp256r1)

- a: FFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC
- b: 5AC635D8AA3A93E7B3EBBD55769886BC651D06B0CC53B0F63BCE3C3E27D2604B
- p: FFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
- x: 5F921B550C05812CF35BAE27B3A2085709DC97824C1C120F8FA357297D5CB875
- y: 8F14DF103FD4B7DF68DACC110F592CEE0637810087A39D371A13D75DFDEB890F

I load it up into BIGNUMs, run all operations such as BN_mul, BN_add etc... I end up with:

> lhs (y2): a large number (64 bytes)

> rhs (x3 + ax + b): a very large number (96 bytes)

So obviously not the same. Maybe i'm doing something wrong here? using wrong parameters?

I searched further, found some code snippets **applying (mod p)** to both sides of the equation. When I apply it, I end up with lhs == rhs. Now i'm really confused because I expected this to fail, yet it succeeds... Maybe it's coincidental (because of mod)... Is my logic even correct? Maybe my EC point is valid after all...

I don't have deep cryptographic knowledge, just trying to work with OpenSSL API...

UPDATE:
After more research/tests and verifying against other examples on the net, I think I'm getting correct result (y2 = x3 + ax + b) mod p...
Since i'm also performing other checks (x > 0 && x < p && y > 0 && y < p), i have no idea what else can be verified...  there's just no way for this verification to fail)...

Hmm does anyone have an example of invalid point on secp256r1?

Related posts:

[Verify that ECPoint is valid on EllipticCurve object given x y coordinates and curve name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68350888/verify-that-ecpoint-is-valid-on-ellipticcurve-object-given-x-y-coordinates-and-c)

[Elliptic curve point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663893/elliptic-curve-point/6664005#6664005)

https://neilmadden.blog/2017/05/17/so-how-do-you-validate-nist-ecdh-public-keys/

Comment: The point you have provided is on the curve that you have provided. We don't know why the 3rd party client is rejecting it. Perhaps it is thinks it's for a different elliptic curve than secp256r1. There are several common 256-bit curves in use. Or perhaps it wants the other y coordinate, which is 0x70eb20eec02b4821972533eef0a6d311f9c87f00785c62c8e5ec28a2021476f0. You need to reconfirm with the 3rd party client. Perhaps there was some little thing in their documentation you overlooked, or didn't realize was important because you're not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

Your point is on the curve. Here is javascript to confirm it:

```js
const BN = require('bn.js');

// curve parameters from https://neuromancer.sk/std/x962/prime256v1
const [a,b,p,x,y] = [
  'ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc',
  '5ac635d8aa3a93e7b3ebbd55769886bc651d06b0cc53b0f63bce3c3e27d2604b',
  'ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff',
  '5F921B550C05812CF35BAE27B3A2085709DC97824C1C120F8FA357297D5CB875',
  '8F14DF103FD4B7DF68DACC110F592CEE0637810087A39D371A13D75DFDEB890F'
].map(hex=>new BN(hex, 'hex', 'be'));

// Curve equation: y^2 ≡ x^3+ax+b (mod p)
const lhs = y.pow(new BN(2)).mod(new BN(p));
const rhs = x.pow(new BN(3)).add(a.mul(x)).add(b).mod(new BN(p));

console.log(lhs.toString(16))
console.log(rhs.toString(16))
console.log(lhs.eq(rhs))
```

Two things that may trip you up:

1. All of these hex values are big-endian. Many crypto libraries work in little-endian, so you may need to reverse the byte sequence of the x and y coordinates before sending them to the 3rd-party client.
2. Many libraries expect only a single coordinate to be provided, and, depending on the use case, a sign bit to disambiguate the other coordinate when the single coordinate is mapped back to the curve. The hex may need to be preceded by certain hex codes to indicate the data format. You need to know what exact format the 3rd-party client is expecting.

Try sending 32 random bytes to the 3rd-party client, and do this a dozen times. If some are accepted, then you at least know that the client is expecting a 32-byte sequence. With this curve, I think that around 50% of 32-byte sequences will be valid single coordinates that can be mapped back to the curve.